# Idiomatic way of mapping across Optional with void method

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

I have a `Optional` and want to call a function with its' contents if present, and throw if not. The problem is `map` will not take a void method.

```
    File file;
    //...
    Optional maybeFile  = Optional.ofNullable(file);
    //..
    maybeFile
        .map(f -> writeTo(f, "stuff")) //Compile error: writeTo() is void
        .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException("File not set"));
```

How should I implement this while keeping `writeTo` void?

Comment: Perhaps you want `peek` instead of `map`?

Comment: @Druckles no `peek` in `Optional`...

Comment: Good point. I don't know why I always assume there is ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`orElseThrow` returns the File object if present and so you can write it as

```
writeTo(maybeFile.orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException("File not set")), "stuff");
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ifPresentOrElse`, which takes 2 consumers:

```
maybeFile.ifPresentOrElse(
    f -> writeTo(f, "stuff"), 
    () -> {
    //absent, so throw exception
    throw new IllegalStateException("File not set");
});
```

Comment: This is only available in Java 9

Answer (score 1):

Although gives no real advantage, you can always change the method signature to:
`Void writeTo(...)`

and then capture the result as `Optional.of(writeTo())`

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't care (well it's a `void` return type) about the result, you can simply do:

```
Optional.ofNullable(f)
            .map(file -> {
                writeTo(file, "");
                return "dummy";
            })
            .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException("File not set"));
```

But then again, this seems very wrong to me, instead of a simple `if(f!= null) { ... }`